# Accessing Azure Storage from VM using Managed Identity

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-managed-identity, azure-vm

I am trying to access an Azure Storage resource from an Azure Windows VM using a Managed Identity.

I have followed the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage but the Access section in the tutorial is done using .NET, which I'm unfamiliar with.

Instead, I would like to list the content of the blob using a combination of Powershell and Managed Identity from the VM, as this fits my use case. Is this possible, because I can't seem to find any example online? If it is, does anyone have a working example please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a combination of `Connect-AzAccount -Identity` and `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` could work. Haven't tested though :\

Comment: Also could you please refer this :https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-manage-user-assigned-managed-identities.md#configure-azure-powershell-locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have fulfilled all the prerequisites

- Enable system-assigned managed identity on Azure Windows VM. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage#enable
- Grant your VM system-assigned managed identity to an Azure Storage container. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-windows-access-storage#grant-access-1

To access the content of the blob using Powershell you can use following commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
#Get blobs in a container by using the pipeline
Get-AzStorageContainer -Name container* | Get-AzStorageBlob -IncludeDeleted
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/connect-azaccount?view=azps-7.4.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstorageblob?view=azps-7.4.0